# Erro "Missing '[' at start of message send expression"

Tags: mobile, objective-c

Boa noite a todos, estou realizando a integração do SDK da Moip(um gateway de pagamento) mas meu conhecimento é mais em swift(que iniciei os estudos há alguns meses).

Eles disponibilizam o sdk para criptagrafia de dados sensíveis de cartão de crédito, porém estou recebendo um erro aparentemente simples mas que não sei como resolver, como se estivesse faltando um colchetes na linha de código.

```
#import "MoipCrypt.h"
#import <MoipSDK/MoipSDK.h>

@implementation MoipCrypt

NSString *myPublicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----CHAVE PUBLICA-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
[MoipSDK importPublicKey:myPublicKey];

@end
```

O erro é na linha

```
[MoipSDK importPublicKey:myPublicKey];
```

Onde aparecem as seguintes mensagens:

Expected ']'
Expected identifier or '('
Missing '[' at start of message send expression

Mesmo a solução dada pelo xcode ("Insert ';'") só causa outros erros de sintaxe.

O link do github do sdk é o seguinte:

[Moip Encryption sdk-ios](https://github.com/moip/moip-encryption-sdk-ios)

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre pois você não está declarando isto dentro de um método, desta forma fica somente como código largado dentro de um arquivo

tente assim:

```
#import "MoipCrypt.h"
#import 

@implementation MoipCrypt

-(void) anyFunction{

    NSString *myPublicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----CHAVE PUBLICA-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    [MoipSDK importPublicKey:myPublicKey];
}

@end
```